# Logging full stack trace (including line number) in ASP.NET Health Monitoring

Tags: asp.net, stack-trace, health-monitoring

I've just health monitoring set up on my website so that it logs errors to a database and sends me an email. However, the logged errors do not contain a full stack trace with a line number showing the line of code that caused the error - it only lists the method in which the error was raised, but not the line number inside that actually caused the problem. Here is a sample from an email message:

```
** Events **
---------------
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 11/6/2015 10:38:24 AM
Event time (UTC): 11/6/2015 10:38:24 AM
Event ID: xxxx Event sequence: 6 Event occurrence: 1 Event detail code: 0

Process information:
    Process ID: 1724
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxxx

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.Exception
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

Request information:
    Request URL: xxxxxx
    Request path: /xxxx.aspx
    User host address: xxxx
    User: xxxx
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: Forms
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxx

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 26
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\xxxx
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at TestPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

As you can see from the Thread information section at the bottom, the message only goes so far as to point that Page_Load caused the error, but doesn't indicate the line number that did so. Could this information be sent using Health Monitoring?

Edit: My web.config section is as follows:

```
 <!-- Health Monitoring -->
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
      <eventMappings>
        <clear/>

        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
      </eventMappings>

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
          name="EmailWebEventProvider" buffer="false"
          from="xxx" to="xxx"
          subjectPrefix="xxxx Website Runtime Error: " />

        <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823"
  buffer="false" name="SqlWebEventProvider"
  type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
      </providers>

      <rules>
        <clear/>
        <add name="All Errors To Database" eventName="All Errors" provider="SqlWebEventProvider"
  profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />

        <add name="All Errors To E-Mail" eventName="All Errors" provider="EmailWebEventProvider"
  profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:00" />
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
```

Comment: did you tried any solution about it ? IMHO, useful   http://mvolo.com/asp-net-health-monitoring-8-years-later for reflecting about *Health Monitoring*, you're right not useful for answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You will need the pdb files alongside the assemblies to get the line numbers included in the stack trace.